# Store a servlet inside packages or not?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a web application using servlets, and I just read in a book for servlets that

> Since most servlets are stored in a package..

and I am wondering, what if I don't use packages? And in the web.xml file I code:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name> MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 0 </load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

instead of using a package and write this

```
<servlet-class>foo.myproject.MyServlet</servlet-class>
```

My question is this, is there any reason to put my servlet inside package(s)?

Comment: You can test it and see the results by yourself.

Comment: hm, i can't do it. It goes to default package.

Comment: Then you already have your answer. You cannot have a class without a package, so your statement is invalid.

Comment: yes indeed. I got confused from the book where says "most servlets..". Are there any others that don't? (I thought that moment) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your servlet is a class like any other, and I would follow the same practises as for your other classes. e.g. `com.x.y.ShoppingCartServlet`, or similar. You may subdivide your packages to separate business logic from the deployment/container mechansim (e.g. `com.x.y.servlets.ShoppingCart`), but again, that's no different to how packages are generally used within Java.

Your full package name will have to be specified in your deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you don't specify a package, you are still in the "default" package. The reason to put your servlet into a package is the same as any other Java class. You do it for the purposes of avoiding naming conflicts and logically dividing your classes for your domain.

Answer (score 2):

In a production environment, multiple programmers may be developing servlets for the same server. So, placing all the servlets in the top-level servlet directory results in a massive hard-to-manage directory and risks name conflicts when two developers accidentally choose the same servlet name. Packages are the natural solution to this problem. Using packages results in changes in the way the servlets are created, the way that they are compiled, and the way they’re invoked.

And coming to technical point of view servlet is just like any other class.So rules are the same for it :)

Answer (score 0):

As any other POJO, servlets should also be packaged according to the functionality they are providing. Its a good way of organizing the code.